# "Reverse" wrong parsed date

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

we run a REST-webservice which consumes different data, my current issue belongs to a date, received as String and parsed by a java.text.SimpleDateFormat (java 8):

We received a lot (>50k) of 'wrong' formatted Strings, which were parsed by the SimpleDateFormat anyways.

The SimpleDateFormat is configured with the pattern "yyyy-MM-dd".
We received Strings the other way around "dd-MM-yyyy".

For Example the String "07-07-1950" was parsed to the date "0012-10-31" (Starting from July in year 7, added 1950 days).

We fixed the implementation, so these Strings are now parsed as expected. But we have all the corrupt dates in the system. The final question is now:

Is there a way to conclude from the date "0012-10-31" to possible original inputs (e.g. "07-07-1950", "07-06-1980" and maybe more...)?

Best regards

Comment: By the way, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [Martin Ackermann's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38455831/2568885):

First of all, I simplified the code a bit.

```
public static Map<String, Set<LocalDate>> createDateMapping(LocalDate min, LocalDate max) throws ParseException {
    DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    DateTimeFormatter wrongFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");

    final Map<String, Set<LocalDate>> inputMappings = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (LocalDate date = min; !date.isAfter(max); date = date.plusDays(1)) {
        final String incorrectlyFormattedDate = date.format(wrongFormat);
        final String key = targetFormat.format(targetFormat.parse(incorrectlyFormattedDate));
        if (!inputMappings.containsKey(key)) {
            inputMappings.put(key, new TreeSet<>());
        }
        inputMappings.get(key).add(date);
    }

    return inputMappings;
}
```

Easily fixing the invalid dates depends on what is the range of valid dates.
For example if `max=2016-12-31` then the following table shows the number of unique dates that are fixable/ambiguous depending on `min`

```
min         fixable ambiguous
-----------------------------
1990-01-01  9862    0
1980-01-01  8827    2344
1970-01-01  5331    5918
1960-01-01  1832    9494
1950-01-01  408     10950
1940-01-01  314     11054
1930-01-01  218     11160
1920-01-01  165     11223
1910-01-01  135     11263
1900-01-01  105     11303
```

Ambiguous matches for invalid dates occur at about 30 year intervals so if the actual dates fall in a period of 30 years then you are in luck

```
    LocalDate max = LocalDate.of(2016, Month.DECEMBER, 31);
    LocalDate min = max.minusYears(30);
    Map<String, Set<LocalDate>> invalidDateMapping = createDateMapping(min, max);
    long reversibleCount = invalidDateMapping.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getValue().size() == 1).count(); // 10859
    long ambiguousCount = invalidDateMapping.size() - reversibleCount; // 50
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a way to find possible inputs:

I can use Calendar to iterate through possible dates, parsing the dates in  the "wron"g way, and build a map with these information.

```
public static Map<String, Collection<String>> createDateMapping() throws ParseException
{
    final DateFormat targetFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final DateFormat wrongFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");

    //starting today
    final Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    final Map<String, Collection<String>> inputMappings = new HashMap<>();

    //rolling down to year zero is quite time consuming, back to year 1899 should be enough...
    while (cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) > 1899)
    {
        //creating the "wrong" date string
        final String formattedDate = wrongFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        final String key = targetFormat.format(targetFormat.parse(formattedDate));

        if (!inputMappings.containsKey(key))
        {
            inputMappings.put(key, new ArrayList<>());
        }

        inputMappings.get(key).add(targetFormat.format(cal.getTime()));

        //roll calendar to previous day
        cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, false);

        if (cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR) == 1)
        {
            //roll down the year manually, since it is not rolled down automatically
            cal.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, false);

            //roll down the day again, to start at the last day of the year again
            cal.roll(Calendar.YEAR, false);
        }
    }

    return inputMappings;
}
```

by the use of this method I can:

```
final Map<String, Collection<String>> dateMapping = createDateMapping();

System.out.println(dateMapping.get("0012-10-31"));//[2011-05-07, 1980-06-07, 1950-07-07, 1919-08-07]
```

It will not solve the problem completely, but is at least a good starting point - hopefully there are some dates with more explicit results.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able to figure out the original date of the corrupted input, but you should be able to find all corrupted dates and perhaps find a way to re-consume that data. This is because each date was altered by an unknown number of days, and reversing that process would require you to know *either* the number of days *or* the starting date, and it looks like you don't have that here.

That said, it will actually be fairly easy to narrow down any dates that were corrupted.

The largest value you will be given for a month should be 12. That means the latest "year" for your corrupted data will be the year 12. If your dates run right up to the present, the largest year (which was incorrectly parsed as days) will be 2016, which would be converted to about 5.5 years. So any dates with years below 18 or 19 are corrupted, and you should be able to at least remove them.

The only edge case here is if you have dates that have years that will validly land in the early teens. If that's the case, you'd have to go through those by hand. But that seems unlikely.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried setting **SimpleDateFormat** **Lenient** to **false**

```
    package test;           

    import java.text.ParseException;            
    import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;          
    import java.util.Date;          

    public class Test {         

        public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {          
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");          
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");          
            dateFormat1.setLenient(false);          
            dateFormat2.setLenient(false);          
            Date d = null;          
            String invalidDate = "07-06-1980";          
        try {           
            d = dateFormat1.parse(invalidDate);         
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            System.out.println("reversed date " + invalidDate);         
            d = dateFormat2.parse(invalidDate);         
        }           

        System.out.println(parsed date " + dateFormat1.format(d));          
    }           
}
```

> reversed date 07-06-1980
>
> parsed date 1980-06-07

Comment: The question was not about, how parse the date correctly, or how to avoid wrong parsing - it was about conclusion from already wrong parsed date to original input(s)